# Calculate distance between user's location and a fixed location

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, geolocation, latitude-longitude

I am receiving multiple restaurants' latitude/longitude from a server. I want to calculate the distance between each restaurant and the user's current latitude/longitude.

Comment: You've found user's current location? or, you have problem finding that?

Comment: thanks for replying me: i have user current locations and my restaurants lat long are mutable array how to access these lat long for finding distance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you have a list of places (one way or the other) you can the get the distance to (or from) these using CoreLocation to calculate this with distanceFromLocation:

Answer (score 39):

You can use *distanceFromLocation:* method of *CLLocation* which returns the distance in meters between two *CLLocation's*.

```
CLLocation *currentLoc = /* Assume you have found it */;
CLLocation *restaurantLoc = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:restaurantLat longitude:restaurantLng];
CLLocationDistance meters = [restaurantLoc distanceFromLocation:currentLoc];
// Go ahead with this
```

Comment: thanks for replying me: i have user current locations and my restaurants lat long are mutable array how to access these lat long for finding distance.

Comment: You have only one array or two arrays for lat and long separately?

Answer (score 2):

You can use an API provided by Google for the same. [The Google Distance Matrix API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/distancematrix/)

Its perfect for finding distance.
Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

## Swift 3

```
func calculateDistanceFromUser(location:CLLocation)->CLLocation!{
    if let userLocation = self.userUpdatedLocation{ //CLLocation
        let meters = location.distance(from: userLocation)
        return meters
    }
    return nil
}
```